# Fetching same data again and again from server using android volley?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Hi Guys am new for android development a day back only i have started using volley form fetching data from server .  Now my problem is am fetching json response from server and setting it into recycler adapter and saving it in sharedpreferences.  I have written volley call in oncreateview method my doubt is  after switching between the activities again when i revisit that fragment its fetching the same data from server and saving it in sharedpreferences like wise data getting doubled each time i visit that fragment here let me post my  code:

This is my Fragment Code:

```
public class Task extends Fragment {
    private static final String MY_PREFERENCE_KEY = "yogan";
    private List<Model_Task_List> model_task_lists;

    //Creating Views
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Task_List_Adapter taskadapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RequestQueue yog;
    Task_DB taskobj = new Task_DB(getContext());
    String yogan;
    AppController app;
    RequestQueue queue;
    String Url;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        Gson gsong = new Gson();


        String jsons = sharedPreferences.getString(MY_PREFERENCE_KEY, "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model_Task_List>>() {
        }.getType();
        model_task_lists = gsong.fromJson(jsons, type);
        if (model_task_lists == null) {
            model_task_lists = new ArrayList<Model_Task_List>();
        }


        //Showing a progress dialog


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.login, 0);
        yogan = sharedPreferences.getString("user_id", null);
       queue= AppController.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
         Url = "http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/xxxx/xxx.svc/getlist/GetTask/" + yogan;
        //Creating a json array request

        JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String server_response = response.toString();
                        try {
                            JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                            JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("GetTaskResult"));
                            for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                                Model_Task_List modelobj = new Model_Task_List();

                                JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                modelobj.setSubject(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Subject"));
                                modelobj.setUserName(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("UserName"));
                                modelobj.setTaskStatus(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("TaskStatus"));

                                model_task_lists.add(modelobj);
                                taskadapter = new Task_List_Adapter(model_task_lists, getContext());
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(taskadapter);
                                taskadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                                //


                            }


                            //Finally initializing our adapter


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("yog", error.toString());
                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
queue.start();
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);



        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
     queue.stop();
        SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        editor = sharedpref.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String god = gson.toJson(model_task_lists);
        editor.putString(MY_PREFERENCE_KEY, god);
        editor.commit();
        super.onStop();
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

This is my Appcontroller class:

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;



    public class AppController extends android.app.Application {
        private static AppController mInstance;
        private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private static Context mCtx;

        private AppController(Context context) {
            mCtx = context;
            mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                    new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                        private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                                cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

                        @Override
                        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                            return cache.get(url);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                            cache.put(url, bitmap);
                        }
                    });
        }

        public static synchronized AppController getInstance(Context context) {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = new AppController(context);
            }
            return mInstance;
        }

        public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
            if (mRequestQueue == null) {
                // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
                // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
            }
            return mRequestQueue;
        }

        public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }

        public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
            return mImageLoader;
        }
    }
```

I hope you guys would have understand my problem am facing i would be very glad i someone help me Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Just make another key('First_Time') in SharedPreferences with a boolean value. Check this value before making the server call. If the value is false then make the server call and set the value to true. So when you re enter the fragment next time, the value will be true and server call will not be made.

In you Fragment's onCreate method -

```
SharedPreferences sharedpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
//Check if key exists
if(!sharedPrefs.contains("First_Time")){
    editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("First_Time", true);
}
```

Now before making the volley call check -

```
if(sharedpref.getBoolean("First_Time")){ //Checking if Fragment launched first time
    //Set this value to false so that it doesn't execute next time.
    editor = sharedpref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("First_Time", false);

   //Now make your volley call for the first and the last time here.
}
```

Comment: can you share some snippet

Comment: then there is no problem with my volley code right ?  Am making in HTTP GET method  to bind this recycler view

Comment: Yes that code looks fine. But alsomake sure to initialise your adapter when you open the fragment second time as at that time volley request will not be made.

Comment: then how to fetch if new data from server

Comment: There could be many ways to do that. If new data sent regularly then you download it everytime. If you want it at regular intervals then you could set up a service which will wake up at certain time intervals and download the data for you and save it or set the sharedpreference variable to true. Another way could be to use GCM but that will require more server side code.

Comment: Here is my requirement need to fetch the data from server and save it in sharedpreference whenever i get new data from server need to fetch it and save it in sharedpref  how can be done it does above code will do it

Comment: How often is new data available on server?

Comment: it depends but i sure frequently needs to fetch from server

Comment: I guess you could remove the sharedpreferences then completely and just completely sync your app with the server. Fetch the live data every time and show it to user.

Comment: then where to save that data

Comment: Why do you need to save the data. Just parse it show it.

Comment: let me explain it clearly once i fetch the data from server i must store it locally whenever i gets new data from server  is present it should be saved like wise i must do so tell me which is the best way to meet my requirement

Comment: Implement GCM or any similar service. Whenever there is new data on the server, send a push to android device and set the sharedpreference to true. This way the next time Fragment is opened, it will again download the latest data. You can paginate your server side data so that only recent data is sent not all at once. Store it where ever you want.

Comment: By using Intent service can i achieve that

Comment: Yes you can. Do as per your requirement.